# Delete and Update Query in one

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

```
cmd1.CommandText = "Delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID = @p1";
cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE tblproductinformation AS pInfo JOIN tblindividualproduct AS iProduct ON iProduct.Code = pInfo.Code SET pInfo.Quantity = pInfo.Quantity - 1 WHERE iProduct.ProductID = @p1";
cmd1.Connection = conn;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "");
for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
   {
      string val = ids[i];
      cmd1.Parameters[0].Value = val;
      cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
```

i have tried this code but i cant seem to make it work. Update query is the only one working. I want to delete row on one table and update the quantity of the other table. how can i do this?

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so include it in your question

Comment: You are setting the CommandText once and then setting it again, which REPLACES the first value.  If you want the CommandText to contain BOTH statements then you have to assign ONE String that contains BOTH statements.  I'm not sure about for MySQL but with SqlClient you separate multiple statements with a semicolon so that would be the first thing I'd try.

Comment: @wwarren: no errors, it just dont work.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: I have tried that method but also doesnt work. only one query is being triggered.

Comment: Did you try with a semicolon in between?

Comment: like this? `cmd1.CommandText = "Delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID = @p1; UPDATE tblproductinformation AS pInfo JOIN tblindividualproduct AS iProduct ON iProduct.Code = pInfo.Code SET pInfo.Quantity = pInfo.Quantity - 1 WHERE iProduct.ProductID = @p1";` yes already

Comment: What happens when you use both statements separated by the semicolon?  Does the UPDATE still work and the DELETE not or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I wrong or you try to UPDATE using, in the WHERE clause, the ProductID that you have just deleted in the first statement?

```
cmd1.CommandText = @"UPDATE tblproductinformation AS pInfo JOIN tblindividualproduct AS iProduct 
                     ON iProduct.Code = pInfo.Code SET pInfo.Quantity = pInfo.Quantity - 1 
                     WHERE iProduct.ProductID = @p1;
                     Delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID = @p1;
```

Just invert the order of the statements.

Of course this assumes that you use a single SQL text with the two commands separated by the semicolon. In you question the error is simply caused by an overwriting of the command text with the last command (the UPDATE), and could be solved also by two separate commands but UPDATE first, DELETE last.

Comment: i have two databases, one is individual product with product id and product code and 1 is product info with only product code but have the quantity. I want to delete the product in the individualproduct and adjust the quantity in productinfo. i use the 2 codes(pInfo.Code,Iproduct.Code) to connect the two databases so that it selects the product ID and then subtract the quantity by 1.

Comment: but these are being executed against the same connection... ?

Comment: Something doesn't sound quite right here. You delete a product, but you want to decrease the quantity just by one? Logic seems to require a delete also in the productinfo table if there is no more product. However, if you delete first in the product table then you cannot find a record in the productinfo because the WHERE cannot find any product

Answer (score 1):

Don't really know why you are trying to do 2 commands in a single statement. Do the following. Will definitely work:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(commandText1, connection))
    {
    }

    using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(commandText2, connection))
    {
    }
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to run this?

```
//command text in one block
string cmdText = @"Delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID IN ({0})
                                UPDATE tblproductinformation AS pInfo JOIN tblindividualproduct AS iProduct ON iProduct.Code = pInfo.Code SET pInfo.Quantity = pInfo.Quantity - 1 WHERE iProduct.ProductID IN ({0})";

cmdText = string.Format(cmdText, string.Join(",", ids));

cmd1.CommandText = cmdText;
cmd1.Connection = conn;            
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Best,
Daniel

Comment: evanmcdonnal is right. The update part will applied to zero rows.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you set the command to delete you change the value to the update command.

```
cmd1.CommandText = "Delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID = @p1";
cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE tblproductinformation AS pInfo JOIN tblindividualproduct AS iProduct ON iProduct.Code = pInfo.Code SET pInfo.Quantity = pInfo.Quantity - 1 WHERE iProduct.ProductID = @p1";
```

Both those lines call the setter for `CommandText` so only the second line actually gets executed. Besides that SQL would never work. Your where is using the same value for the key and your first command would delete that column so the update would be applied to zero rows.

Instead, within your for loop;

```
cmd1.Connection = conn;
for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
   {
      cmd1.CommandText = "Delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID = @p1";
      cmd1.Parameters[0].Value = ids[i];
      cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

      cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE tblproductinformation AS pInfo JOIN tblindividualproduct AS iProduct ON iProduct.Code = pInfo.Code SET pInfo.Quantity = pInfo.Quantity - 1 WHERE iProduct.ProductID = @p1";         

      cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
```

I don't know how you intend to decide which id's get deleted and which get updated but if you're planning to use different queries for different id's then you need to set the command inside the for loop so that it can be changed from one id to the next. Just as a random example you could do `i+=2` as your increment condition in the loop and then delete even id's while updating odd ones. That doesn't really make sense though, more likely you only want one of the two commands.

EDIT: One final disclaimer, **this is in no way best practices** and it's not intended to be. There are fundamental problems with the control flow of the OP's code and I only intend to address those. As shown in another answer there are other obvious problems such as the lack of using statements when the objects in question implement `IDisposable` which I have chosen not to address.

Comment: i have two databases, one is individual product with product id and product code and 1 is product info with only product code but have the quantity. I want to delete the product in the individualproduct and adjust the quantity in productinfo. i use the 2 codes(pInfo.Code,Iproduct.Code) to connect the two databases so that it selects the product ID and then subtract the quantity by 1.

Comment: @MixAustria ok, I put in an edit that i think will do what you want. It assumes the id is the same for both queries, runs the first, updates the cmd, then runs the second. Another, better option, would be to just create to instance of `SqlCommand`, one for each query, and execute both in the for loop.